# Merging the data to a new DatabaseMongodb collection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get the data from one collection and update to the new collection in Mongodb Database. The documents are getting updated with new value and write to the new collection but the New collection is not updating with the documents .Can anyone please suggest how to write the data into new collection .

```
private String Method(String system , String period) {
 mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);
        MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
        collectionDB = database.getCollection(Sample_TMP);
        String collectionName = "SampleCollection";
      
        {
            Consumer<Document> processBlock = new Consumer<Document>() {
                int count;
                @Override
                public void accept(Document document) {
                    System.out.println(document);
                }
            };
                 String collectionName = "SampleCollection";

            if (!mongoOps.collectionExists(collectionName)) {
                collectionNew = mongoOps.createCollection(collectionName);
                LOG.info("Collection %s was successfully created", collectionName);
            } else {
                collectionNew = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName);
            }

          List<? extends Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
                    new Document()
                            .append("$match", new Document()
                                    .append("Type.key", "SS")
                                    .append("key", "PP")   
                            ),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                    .append("ID", "$_id")
                                    .append("Period", value)
                                    
                                    
                                    )
                           .append("Amount", true)
                            ),
                  
                    new Document()
                            .append("$out", collectionNew)
            );
            AggregateIterable<Document> resultsPipeline = mergeCollection.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(false);
            
            List<? extends Bson> pipeline2 = Arrays.asList(
                    new Document()
                            .append("$match", new Document()
                                    .append("key", "type")
                                    .append("key", "value")
                                  
                            ),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                    .append("ID", "$_id")
                                    .append("Period", period2)
                                   
                                    )
                                   
                                    .append("Reserve", true)
                            ),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$project", new Document()
                                    .append("_id", 0.0)
                                    .append("amount", Decimal128.parse("0.0"))
                               
                            ),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$merge", new Document()
                                    .append("into", collectionNew)
                            )
            );

        AggregateIterable<Document> resultsPipeline2 =  collectionNew.aggregate(pipeline2)
                .allowDiskUse(false);
            
            

Mongoshell Query:

    db.getCollection("SampleCollection").aggregate(
            [
                { 
                    "$match" : { 
                        "Key1" : "SS", 
                        "key2" : "OUT", 
                        
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "$addFields" : { 
                        'RecordID':'$_id',
                        "Period" : Period, 
                        
                        "Type" : { 
                            "key" : "XX", 
                            "value" : "Outstanding"
                        }, 
                 
                        'Transaction.RolledOverReserve' : true
                        
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "$project" : { 
                        "_id" : 0.0, 
                        "ClosingAmt" : 0.0, 
                        "UnsignedAmount" : 0.0,
                        "Reserve":0
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "$out" : "UpdatedCollection"
                }
            ], 
            { 
                "allowDiskUse" : false
            }
        );
        
        db.getCollection("SampleCollection").aggregate(
            [
                { 
                    "$match" : { 
                        "key" : "SS", 
                        "key" : "EXO", 
                       
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "$addFields" : { 
                        'RecordID':'$_id',
                        "Period" : nextPeriod, 
                         
                        "Month" : nextMonth,
                        "Type" : { 
                            "key" : "XX", 
                            "value" : "Outstanding"
                        }, 
                      
                        "Reserve" : "$Amount",
                        'Identifier':{
                            $concat:[
                                '$ID.key',
                                ' Opening Balance'
                            ]
                        },
                        'Transaction.RolledOverReserve' : true
        
                                            
                    }
                }, 
               
                { 
                    "$merge" : { 
                        "into" : "UpdatedCollection"
                    }
                }
            ], 
            { 
                "allowDiskUse" : false
            }
        );
```

Comment: For these types of questions I always recommend you first create the aggregation outside of Java/Spring.  First, create the Aggregation using mongoshell and shape the data as desired, then port the mongoshell aggregation to Java.  The reason for this approach is to understand first what the database needs to accomplish the task, then identify what options the programming language offers to achieve the desired aggregation.  With the current MongoDB Java driver (version 4.3) there are many aggregation helpers.  You may find that Spring Templates have their own APIs too that must be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I have created the aggregation by using mongoshell and shape the data but writing of  data to new collection is not happening .Can you please suggest

Comment: Please include the mongoshell aggregation in this post

Comment: Included Mongoshell Javascript code but I need it in java

Comment: I think I understand what you are seeking.  I was starting to look into this and i found the Java code is incomplete.  Please provide a valid example of code, and also - it would be helpful to see sample data too.

Comment: @barrypicker ,Thank you for your reply , The above code is working fine and able to see the documents count also but the issue is the documents are not updating into the new collection , it looks like merging issue .I have tried different ways but all are throwing exceptions .Could you please suggest how to write the results in New collection in JSON format

Comment: Hi @Rose, I would like to help, but the code example above does not compile.  Please review and reply...